# how to insert item from one list to other at position which doesnot contains alphanumeric

Tags: python

these are my lists

```
i=["a","b"]
j=["abc","(3)","ab & ac", "(1,4)","xyz"]
```

and I want my output be like this

```
j=["abc","a","ab & ac","b","xyz"]
```

and i tried like this,

```
val=0
for item in j:
    if item.isalpha():
        pass
    else:
        elem=i[val]
        j.replace(item, elem)
        val=val+1
```

How to insert item from one list to other at position which does not contains alphanumeric?

Comment: You know what's awesome? Being able to close a question as off-topic because the asker didn't even try.

Comment: I suggest rereading the answers to your previous question; this is a trivial variant.  (BTW, if `ab & ac` is alphanumeric, how is `(3)` not?  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "ab & ac" is **not** alphanumeric (because of the & and whitespaces) and that you made a typo, this will do the trick.

```
def removeNonAlpha(i,j):
    indexI = 0
    indexJ = 0
    while indexJ < len(j):
        if not j[indexJ].isalnum():
            j[indexJ] = i[indexI]
            indexI += 1
        indexJ += 1
    return j

>>>i=["a","b", "c"]
>>>j=["abc","(3)","ab & ac", "(1,4)","xyz"]
>>>removeNonAlpha(i,j)
['abc', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'xyz']
```

This code also assumes that you have enough elements in i to make complete replacements for j.

If for some special reasons you need to allow **&** signs (which would imply that you would also need to allow the whitespaces) here is the alternative:

```
def removeNonAlpha(i,j):
    indexI = 0
    indexJ = 0
    while indexJ < len(j):
        if not j[indexJ].replace('&', '').replace(' ', '').isalnum():
            j[indexJ] = i[indexI]
            indexI += 1
        indexJ += 1
    return j

>>>i=["a","b"]
>>>j=["abc","(3)","ab & ac", "(1,4)","xyz"]
>>>removeNonAlpha(i,j)
['abc', 'a', 'ab & ac', 'b', 'xyz']
```

Comment: I dont want to remove "ab & ac"

Comment: @ApoorvaShankar is & sign the only exception or are there more? Also would you allow something like "ab &"?

Answer (score 1):

This will preserve any list element in a list `j`  that has a letter in it

```
[s for s in j if any(c in string.letters for c in s)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a character or string than doesn't occur in any of the strings, you can concatenate the list into a single string using the string .join method, then use a regular expression and the re.sub function to do the replacement.  After that, you can use the .split method to divide the string back into a list:

```
>>> import re
>>> i=["a","b"]; j=["abc","(3)","ab & ac", "(1,4)","xyz"]
>>> js = "|".join(j) # merge j into one string
>>> print js
abc|(3)|ab & ac|(1,4)|xyz
>>> print re.sub("\(.*?\)", i[0], js)
abc|a|ab & ac|a|xyz
>>> print re.sub("\(.*?\)", i[0], js, count=1)
abc|a|ab & ac|(1,4)|xyz
>>> for r in i:
        js = re.sub("\(.*?\)", r, js, count=1)


>>> print js
abc|a|ab & ac|b|xyz
```

That for loop at the end shows you how to do it.  The parenthesized fields will be filled in, one at a time, from left to right. To put it back into a list:

```
jnew = js.split("|")
```

...and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your definition of "alphanumeric" is. Your example uses isalpha, which "ab & ac" fails, as DSM pointed out. If isalpha is an acceptable definition of "alphanumeric", and it's OK to modify the arrays, then I propose the following:

```
for index, item in enumerate(j):
    if not item.isalpha():
        j[index] = i.pop(0) if i else None
```

There's probably a list comprehension version of this, but it would be messy.

Note that the above code produces the following result, given your sample inputs:

```
['abc', 'a', 'b', None, 'xyz']
```

That's because there aren't actually enough items in i to cover all the non-alphanumeric members of j, so I used None in that case.